# "The request is not supported" [WinError 50] from subprocess.Popen()

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community>python3
Python 3.10.11 (tags/v3.10.11:7d4cc5a, Apr  5 2023, 00:38:17) [MSC v.1929 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import subprocess
>>> subprocess.Popen(['Z:/depot/kJams/Scripting/AutoPin.exe', 'parameter'])
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 971, in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.10_3.10.3056.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\subprocess.py", line 1456, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
OSError: [WinError 50] The request is not supported
```

This was working recently. This is on Windows 10 with all latest OS updates.

[image]

Comment: I'd say the answer is "yes, it's giving you grief."  I can't tell you why though.

Comment: when i move the `AutoPin.exe` to an internal drive, it DOES work. so it has something to do with the fact that it's on a network-mapped drive. but see my screen shot where you can see that i EXPLICITLY allow running apps from that drive

Comment: We really need a [mre] for anyone to be able to speak to this -- code and configuration details complete enough we can run it ourselves without changes to see the problem.

Comment: (Also, pay attention to endpoint security products installed in your test environment; security products that intercept and disable places where a program that isn't expected to start a shell starts a shell are very common, _especially_ on Windows).

Comment: (Endpoint security products being configured with policies that restrict execution of software off network drives is also not unheard of, to mitigate lateral movement -- mind, you _did_ check that you can run the executable in other ways, right?)

Answer (score -1):

This is working on later versions of Python. Maybe Microsoft depreciated something so Python eventually updated it and the change removed it, speculation... Short answer is that the fix might be an update to your running Python interpreter.
[image: Python 3.11.7]

If this does not work then something funky is going on locally (or MS is "testing" things again), I just updated today.

Comment: just tested with 3.11.7, same problem:

  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.11_3.11.2032.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\Lib\subprocess.py", line 1538, in _execute_child
    hp, ht, pid, tid = _winapi.CreateProcess(executable, args,
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
OSError: [WinError 50] The request is not supported

Comment: @TimothyH, if you were never able to reproduce the problem, and haven't found any documentation, changelog, ticket/issue or other references explaining it, how can you confidently claim that it's fixed? Something that boils down to "I can't reproduce this" is better suited for a comment than an answer.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy, you're right... Made assumptions

What is the good thing to do in my case?